# Inserting a script in a query string

Tags: javascript, html, scripting, href, query-string

I have created a script as follows:

```
<script language="JavaScript">
    function mdy(todaysdate) {

        month = todaysdate.getMonth() + 1
        year = todaysdate.getYear() + 1900
        date = todaysdate.getDate()


        return year + "-" + month + "-" + date
    }
</script>

<script language="JavaScript">
    sampleDate1 = new Date()
    document.write(mdy(sampleDate1))
</script>
```

This script displays today's date in yyyy-mm-dd format. I want to include this script into a query string. the link in html is as follows:

```
<a href=https://website.com/orders/213/tickets?membershipCategoryId={membership_level_id}&date=>{member_content_title}</a>
```

I want to have the yyyy-mm-dd to appear in the link right after "date=".

How do I go about doing that?

Comment: You want to include the *result* of the script, not the script itself.

Answer (score 0):

What about

```
document.write("<a href=https://website.com/orders/213/tickets?membershipCategoryId={membership_level_id}&date="+mdy(sampleDate1)+">{member_content_title}</a>")
```

?

Comment: if i do it this way, where do i put the actual script? at the top?

Comment: what do you call "the actual script" ?